# Android: Align views vertically left

Tags: android, layout, view, alignment

I'm trying to align some text views vertically left but it doesn't work properly, could anyone else point me out what's wrong with my code below?

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "left"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/top_spacing"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottom_spacing"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        style="@style/style1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2"
        style="@style/style1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text3"
        style="@style/style1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the TextViews are laid on top of each other at top left corner, am I right?

Comment: yeah they are now overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity = "left"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/top_spacing"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottom_spacing"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    style="@style/style1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text2"
    style="@style/style1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Text1"
    />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text3"
    style="@style/style1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Text2"
    />
```

You never set the `layout_below` attribute. This answer is useful if you choose to use the `RelativeLayout`, or need to, otherwise you would probably be better off using Neoh's and Fahad Ishaque's answers which pretty much say the same thing.

Comment: Ahh, that's the one I missed! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use LinearLayout for your usecase:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity = "left"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/top_spacing"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottom_spacing"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    style="@style/style1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text2"
    style="@style/style1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text3"
    style="@style/style1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace **relative layout** with **linear layout**. Your using all the attributes of a linear layout e.g **orientation**. And please remove nu-necessary tags that belongs to relative layout scheme from the text views.

Comment: I tried linear layout initially but it didn't align the views to the left of the parent.

Comment: add layout_gravity or simple gravity = "left". Add this attribute to layout.

Comment: I was also wondering what's the benefit using linear layout over relative layout in this particular case? Thanks!

Comment: Not any which I can think of. If you use weights, you can save alot of time optimizing for multiple screens.